# Why some functions are not visible in hoogle?

Tags: haskell, hoogle

Why some functions are not visible in `Hoogle`? Example: [ppTopElement](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=ppTopElement)

```
ppTopElement :: Element -> String
        -- Defined in `Text.XML.Light.Output'
```

Is it a bug?

Comment: Your search doesn't have it, but [ppTopElement +xml](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=ppTopElement+%2Bxml) does have it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Workaround: go to [**FPcomplete**](https://www.fpcomplete.com/hoogle) instead.

haskell.org's Hoogle (http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) is quite selective about what it searches, whereas FP Complete's hoogle at https://www.fpcomplete.com/hoogle searches more fully:

### Search more widely than haskell.org's hoogle

https://www.fpcomplete.com/hoogle?q=ppTopElement&env=ghc-7.4.2-stable-13.09

> Searched for: ppTopElement
>
> [`ppTopElement :: Element -> String`](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.4.2/20130829-168/xml/Text-XML-Light-Output.html#v%3appTopElement)
>      [`xml`](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.4.2/20130829-168/xml)  [`Text.XML.Light.Output`](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.4.2/20130829-168/xml/Text-XML-Light-Output.html)
>
> Pretty printing renders XML documents faithfully, with the exception that whitespace may be added/removed in non-verbatim character data.

### Search more flexibly than hayoo

Being a hoogle rather than a hayoo, you can search by type, partial type, partial name, misordered type etc. For instance, [searching for `Element -> String`](https://www.fpcomplete.com/hoogle?q=Element+-%3E+String&env=ghc-7.4.2-stable-13.09) gives lots of functions, some showing, some pretty printing, some just doing the top element.

### Aside: there's a lovely online IDE

BTW, Their online IDE is superb (click on the homepage https://www.fpcomplete.com/ and scroll down to Start a Project). It's slick, pretty, and you can add dependencies easily without tedious `cabal install` problems. I've been tempted to even use it at home where I have ghc installed!

Comment: I feel this starts to read like an ad, but I've been delighted with it since I started using it recently, and I'm not affiliated in any way other than having an account with them.

Comment: Well, initially I thought you were an FP Complete employee. :-)

Comment: @Sibi It's slightly upsetting when I was rereading it to realise that when I'm enthusiastic it sounds like a sales pitch. (That's why I added the comment.) Perhaps I missed my calling as a salesman! (I'm a teacher.)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try [Hayoo](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html?query=ppTopElement) for that.

Hayoo will search all packages from Hackage, including all function and type definitions. Hoogle only searches on standard Haskell libraries.

Also Hayoo can be queried from Emacs in `haskell-mode`.